# Sending HTTP multipart/form-data RESPONSE

Tags: python, http, multipartform-data, httpresponse, cherrypy

so I'm examining an HTTP communication between a printer and a client which tries to install some things on the printer. My goal is to create a simulator for the printer which sends the same HTTP responses as the printer to the client's requests sent during the installation. I have access to all the messages sent using wireshark.

At some point the client sends a request similar to this one:

```
POST /some/address HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=someBoundary
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

--someBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name1"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

oneWordText
--someBoundary--
```

And the printer responds with:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: ...
MIME-Version: 1.0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=boundary

--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=name1
Content-Type: plain/text
Content-Transfer-Encoding: UTF-8

12345
--boundary--
```

No matter what, I can't find a way to send a multipart *response*, all over the internet I can only find ways to send a multipart *POST request*.
Currently I'm using python with CherryPy server to receive the request and even after looking into the documentation I couldn't find an answer.
I thought that copying and sending the whole response body with the appropriate header would work, but it didn't.
So do you have any ideas how this could be done? Should I use a different framework or a language?

Thanks for your answers!